# Are all dynamic equilibrium reactions with neutralization, must also be buffers?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

Reactions like:

$\ce{H2CO3_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} <--> H3O+_{(aq)} + HCO3-_{(aq)}}$

**or**

$\ce{C5H5N_{(aq)} + H2O_{(l)} <--> C5H5NH+_{(aq)} + OH-_{(aq)}}$

Does that mean that the last stage of reaction of a buffer system must be of a weak acid/base?

Comment: With a strong acid or base, the equilibrium will be shifted all the way to the right, hence no buffer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because a buffer is basically a weak acid or weak base as far as I know. These hydronium ions are also like weak acids on top of carbonic acid which is also a weak acid. Carbonic acid is a weak acid. It has a pH of 5 or 6.